# Javascript prototype function: decimal time value to a time string

Tags: javascript, time, function-prototypes

On a project I'm currently working on in JavaScript, I'm using decimal formats so it's easier to calculate with rather than using an hour/minute format in strings (calendar related project). To display the time on the user's screen though, the timecode has to be shown as hh:mm.

I thought it would be great to use a String prototype function for this as it would allow me to use code like:

```
var time = 8.75;
document.write("Meeting at "+time.toTime()); // writes: Meeting at 8:45
```

So far, I've got that almost working, using:

```
String.prototype.toTime = function(){
    var hrs = this.toString().slice(0,this.indexOf("."));
    var min = Math.round(this.toString().slice(this.indexOf("."))/100*60);
    min = min<10 ? "0"+min : min.toString();
    return hrs+":"+min;
}
```

The problem, though, is that this will only work if the variable `time` is a string. Otherwise it will give an undefined error.

Would there be any way of applying the prototype to a different object in JavaScript, so that I don't have to use `time.toString().toTime()`?

Thanks!

Comment: Would `Number.prototype.toTime` help? And you can shorthand to `(""+time).toTime()` in your current code.

Comment: you can use `Object.prototype` as all objects inherit from it.

Comment: Personally I find it to be a cleaner approach to pass the value to a function instead of extending the prototype.

Comment: @FelixKling it's swings and roundabouts, in my experience.  I have what I consider a rather nice implementation of `strftime` which I have both on `Date.prototype` and `Number.prototype`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, you can add to the `Number` prototype. Many people will warn against modifying prototypes, which in many cases is justified. If there is a chance 3rd party scripts will be running alongside yours, it is a danger to modify prototypes.

Secondly, I simplified your code a little, using modulus, and floor to calculate the hrs and mins...

```
Number.prototype.toTime = function(){
  var hrs = Math.floor(this)
  var min = Math.round(this%1*60)
  min = min<10 ? "0"+min : min.toString();
  return hrs+":"+min;
}

var time = 8.25;
console.log("Meeting at "+time.toTime());
```

Comment: You don't have to `toString().split(".")` if you're already manipulating number...`parseInt`,`Math.floor`,etc. can do the trick.

Comment: @Passerby you are quite right... I adjusted the answer accordingly

Comment: Thanks, that makes perfect sense. However, I found one little bug in there: `9.50` will be outputted as "9:03", rather than "9:30". Any idea?

Comment: Oh, I see that your adjustment fixed that. Awesome.

Comment: There is still one small error, for decimals with `.999`, so `8.999` for example comes out as `8:60`, but `8.99` comes out as `8:59`. To correct this, you could manipulate the number to be 2 decimal places before calculating the mod.

Comment: Billy - actually, just changing `var min = Math.round` to `var min = Math.floor` solves that issue. :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Object.prototype.toTime`.

Comment: Why you negativate? It will help you, if you use `prototype` of `Object`

Comment: 1.  because adding to `Object.prototype` is dangerous unless you know _exactly_ what you're doing 2.  Because it then applies to every `Object`, even ones where this method makes no sense.

Comment: Yeah, I know it, but negativate something means a "crazy wrong answer". The solution here applies for your case, but it's not the best beacuse the implict danger. So I dont't think it deserves be negativated :D

Comment: I disagree.  I give down votes to any answer I consider potentially harmful.